# Google Sheets - Comparing a column against a table to retrieve a tag

Tags: google-sheets, compare, array-formulas

If I have a column of values **A**{2,11,101,1001} and I have a table with two columns **C/D**{Tag1/1,Tag2/10,Tag3/100....}

I want to have an array formula that compares the values from A and sees if where they fit in the range... if less than 100 but more than 10 column B should show Tag2 etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A1:A,
 {QUERY(IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(
  REGEXEXTRACT(D1:D&"-"&C1:C, "(\d+)"))), ), "SELECT Col1"),
  REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(D1:D&"-"&C1:C, "SELECT Col1"),"-(.+)")}, 2)), )
```

[image: 9]

Comment: This is perfectly what I asked for... however my real world situation has a circular reference problem happening. The value of A changes based on the value of B, so I need to look one row early for my comparison to avoid a problem. How can I?

Comment: EX: Instead of Tag I have another numeric value. A1 is static, but A2:A add the value of B to the value in A above theirs. I see that if I change the VLOOKUP to A1 It SHOULD look up as desired, but I still get a #REF! error.

Comment: I found my own answer to this one... I needed Iterative Calculations from the Spreadsheet Settings. Thank you!